# For solo elimina número nones javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un pequeño problema con javascript; tengo un for que sólo elimina número nones para borrar elementos de una lista. Les adjunto el código que tengo y el error que me aparece.

```
function borrar() {
  var lista = document.getElementById('lista-dinamica');
  var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item');
  var x = lista.children.length;
  console.log(x);
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    lista.removeChild(elementos[i]);
  }
}
```

Este es el error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>           at borrar (app.js:68)
>           at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:73)
>       borrar @ app.js:68
>       onclick @ index.html:73

Comment: Que es lo que quieres conseguir?

Comment: Los fragmentos de código son para poder probar el código HTML/JS, ya que te dicidiste a usarlos pudiste haber puesto algo funcional, incluyendo el HTML donde se encuentran los elementos `lista-dinamica` y `list-group-item`, de ese modo se habría podido verificar lo que ocurre. Tampoco explicas con toda claridad lo que quieres. A veces ocurre que en las respuestas te pueden sugerir mejores métodos, cuando se ha entendido mejor lo que se quiere lograr.

Comment: Perdón, mi intención es borrar una lista que se llena con la permutación de una cadena de caracteres, el problema es que me elimina solo los número nones y quedan todos los número pares, hasta que se le da click por segunda vez al botón borrar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo pronto tu variable `x` debería ser la longitud de `elementos` no de los hijos de `lista`

```
function borrar() {
  var lista = document.getElementById('lista-dinamica');
  var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item');
  var x = elementos.length;
  console.log(x);
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    lista.removeChild(elementos[i]);
  }
}
```

Pero el problema de fondo [es bastante conocido](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35007791/930271). Cada vez que iteras y eliminas un `elemento` estás modificando `lista`, por tanto el hijo `[i]` de `lista` cada vez será distinto.

Por ejemplo, al arracar tu lista será así:

```
<ul>
    <li> a </li> <!-- elemento[0] -->
    <li> b </li> <!-- elemento[1] -->
    <li> c </li> <!-- elemento[2] -->
    <li> d </li> <!-- elemento[3] -->
</ul>
```

Pero tras la primera iteracción y haber ejecutado, `lista.removeChild(elementos[0]);` lo siguiente a ejecutar es `lista.removeChild(elementos[1]);`

```
<ul>
    <!-- <li> a </li> antiguo elemento[0], ahora eliminado-->
    <li> b </li> <!-- elemento[0] -->
    <li> c </li> <!-- elemento[1] -->
    <li> d </li> <!-- elemento[2] -->
</ul>
```

Por lo que se borrara `<li> c </li>` y no `b`

La solución más habitual es usar un código [como este](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3955238/930271):

```
function borrar() {
    var lista = document.getElementById('lista-dinamica');
    while (lista.firstChild) {
         lista.removeChild(lista.firstChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias, ya hice el cambio y me sigue borrando solo los número nones.

Comment: Ya he entendido tu problema. He modificado la respuesta. Recuerda marcarla como aceptada, si con esto se soluciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias, logre hacer que borrara toda la lista eliminado en cada iteración el elementos[0], pero tu solución es mucho más corta y eficaz.e